# @api Parameters and @wire Functions Ordering

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any guaranteed ordering of these two events in a child LWC:  (1) Population of all passed @api properties (2) Invocation of @wire methods?

In other words, are @api parameter values available to @wire methods reliably/always or not?

Is this documented in Salesforce tech doc anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@api` variables are set before `connectedCallback()` (and are thus available in `connectedCallback()`, whilst `@wire` methods don't get a chance to fire until after `connectedCallback()` is done executing (or, effectively, the first `render()` call finishes executing). This is implicitly guaranteed in the [LWC Component Lifecycle](https://lwc.dev/guide/lifecycle#lifecycle-flow) and [@wire](https://lwc.dev/guide/wire_adapter) documentation. It's not really laid out in the Salesforce LWC documentation, you have to actually look at the LWC OSS.

Comment: Thanks, sfdxfox.  I notice though that when I console.log() the firing of connectedCallback() and my wire functions, the wire functions can sometimes come first.  Do you think that's just a console logging issue?

Comment: I can say, by observation, that reactive wire functions can be called twice - once where the response object is empty (no `data` or `error` properties) and once with the actual wire result (one or other of `data` and `error` set). Perhaps it is the empty call you see before connectedCallback?

Comment: @DaveC If the response is cached, it will be returned, but keep in mind that it will be out of date (stale) until after `connectedCallback()` finishes.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  It sounds like at least the second invocation of the wire will be after the connectedCallback().  You are right Phil, it's just the first 'dud' call of the wire that occurs before connectedCallback().

Answer (score 2):

If you set up your `@wire` arguments to be reactive, then it doesn't matter when the `@api` attributes get set, they will flow through. [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

> We call the wire service reactive in part because it supports reactive variables, which are prefixed with $. If a reactive variable changes, the wire service provisions new data. We say “provisions” instead of “requests” or “fetches” because if the data exists in the client cache, a network request may not be involved.

The **`Mark a Configuration Object Property as Dynamic and Reactive`** section has a more in depth example.

One gotcha in my experience is you may need to wrap any markup in a conditional rendering that only shows once the data exists.

```
<template if:true={myData}>
    <!-- render here -->
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, Adrian.  In this case my wire functions have no input parameters so reactivity does not help me.  I want to use api parameters when the wire returns - in its promise fulfillment -- so I need to know if they are reliably available in that case.